# PHP find multiple currency numbers in string

Tags: php

I'm writing php script which will recognise bank payment reports.
For example, I have this code:

```
$str = "Customer Name /First Polises number - SAT431223 (5.20 eur), BOS32342 (33,85 euro), (32,10 eiro), (78.66 €), €1232,2,  (11.45)"
```

And I need to find all this currency combinations in string, so the input be like this:

`5.20
33.85
32.10
78.66
1232.20
11.45`

How can I do that? I know the function preg_match(), but I don't understand how to write pattern for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match` will give you only first match found. But you can use `preg_match_all` to get array of all matches.

Here's everything you need to know about how to build regex patterns: 
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

You need pattern like this: `/[0-9]+[,.]{1}[0-9]{2}/`

`/` - delimiter, can be other character, but you need it on the beginning and end of the pattern.

`[0-9]` - matches digits
`+` and `{1}`, and `{2}` - they define amount of charaters. `+` is "one or more", number in `{}` is exact number of characters.

`[,.]{1}` - this matches exactly one (`{1}`) character from set of `,.`.

Example code:

```
$matches = array();    
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+[,.]{1}[0-9]{2}/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Result:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '5.20' (length=4)
      1 => string '33,85' (length=5)
      2 => string '32,10' (length=5)
      3 => string '78.66' (length=5)
      4 => string '11.45' (length=5)
```

Comment: Yes, It is exactly what I need! Thank you for explanation on how pattern actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with:

```
/([0-9]+[,.][0-9]+)/g
```

Matching:

- Numbers (zero or more times)
- Dot or Comma
- Numbers (zero or more times)
- Note the g: Global to get all matches

Example and more detailed break-down of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/eH6aX6/1

That will match any `double` values in the provided sentence which are not necessarily currency...

Hope it points you t the correct direction

Comment: g modifier is not exists in php

Comment: @CihanUygun Yup, as per dragoste, `preg_match_all` would do this. I just try to make the regex explanation clear here...

Comment: Yeah `preg_match_all` does g modifier, I get it what you mean ;)